# Validation rule need to update

Tags: validation

Need help to edit my validation rule:

NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Project__r.Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c))) &&
NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Commission_to_360__c)))

||
    CASE(
    Project__r.Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c ,
    "1.50%", "1.50",
    "1.75%", "1.75",
    "2.00%", "2.00",
    "2.25%", "2.25",
    "2.00%", "2.00",
    NULL)

```
<>

CASE(
Commission_to_360__c,
"1.50", "1.50",
"1.75", "1.75",
"2.00", "2.00",
"2.25", "2.25",
"2.00", "2.00",
NULL)
```

I need to edit this rule to exempt and not to fire if "Project__r.Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c" picklist field is populated (regardless of value) AND "Commission_to_360__c" picklist field is blank.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you [edit] to be a little clearer about the expectation - are you trying to define the behavior if one field is blank but not both?

Comment: I need the VR to trigger only if "Commission_to_360__" is being edited and not equal to "Project__r.Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c".  But "Project__r.Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c" field can have a value and "Commission_to_360__" can be blank.

Comment: That's quite different from what you have articulated in your question. Could you please [edit] to clarify (rather than adding comments), and show us what you've tried to achieve this?

Comment: please use the [edit] link on the original post - not comments

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your formula has the correct values for `Commission_to_360__c` without the `%` signs so the `CASE` statement for this field wouldn't be necessary for the comparison.

If I'm not understanding wrong, you could just check the for that field being changed AND populated, so that if the comparison doesn't match, you could still prevent the VR from firing if `Commission_to_360__c` is `NULL`. To do this try something like the following:

```
ISCHANGED(Commission_to_360__c) && 

(CASE(
Project__r.Three_Sixty_Retail_Rate__c ,
"1.50%", "1.50",
"1.75%", "1.75",
"2.00%", "2.00",
"2.25%", "2.25",
"2.00%", "2.00",
NULL)

<>

TEXT(Commission_to_360__c) ) && 
!ISBLANK(TEXT(Commission_to_360__c))
```

Comment: Hi Glen, I tried but got this error:  Error: Field Commission_to_360__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Comment: Yes, picklists are special in formulas. You will have to use different notation because of that. Try !ISBLANK(TEXT(Commission_to_360__c) instead of Commission_to_360__c != NULL. I'll edit the answer knowing that.